# How to validate some custom constraint in symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I have Item entity class, and I must validate it. I have condition that price must be less than 1000. And if price is less than 5, and stock is less 10 it is wrong too. So for first condition I use LessThan Constraint, but what should I do for the second condition?

```
class Item {
   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\LessThan(self::ITEM_MAX_PRICE)
     */
    private float $price;

   /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private int $stock;

}
```

How can I validate this both property's with second condition?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: I already read this, but it is about validation of one property, not it?

Comment: You can put assertions on the class as well.

Comment: In other words, when put on the class, you're interacting with the object (which the custom validator gives you access to).

Comment: It's domain, so personally I would recommend this is logic that should be implemented in domain code. I've added an example doing something similar from a project of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a custom validator. Here's an example from one of my projects (3.4).

Three files:

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraint/HasValidDimensions.php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class HasValidDimensions extends Constraint
{
    public $invalidWidth = 'Invalid width dimension.';
    public $invalidHeight = 'Invalid height dimension.';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `CLASS_CONSTRAINT`. Now, the actual validator gives me access to the different parts (in this case it's a command validator):

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Validator/Constraint/HasValidDimensionsValidator.php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraint;

use AppBundle\Message\Command\PageTemplate\SetPageTemplateDimensions;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class HasValidDimensionsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($setPageTemplateDimensions, Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        /* @var SetPageTemplateDimensions $setPageTemplateDimensions */
        /* @var HasValidDimensions $constraint */

        $pageTemplate = $setPageTemplateDimensions->getPageTemplate();

        if ($setPageTemplateDimensions->getWidth() > $pageTemplate->getWidthReal()) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->invalidWidth)
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }

        if ($setPageTemplateDimensions->getHeight() > $pageTemplate->getHeightReal()) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->invalidHeight)
                ->addViolation()
            ;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the validator on the class:

```
<?php // src/AppBundle/Message/Command/PageTemplate/SetPageTemplateDimensions.php

namespace AppBundle\Message\Command\PageTemplate;

use AppBundle\Validator\Constraint as AppAssert;

/**
 * @AppAssert\HasValidDimensions()
 */
class SetPageTemplateDimensions implements TenantOwnedInterface
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Symfony don't provide a build-in constraint to validate multiples properties between them (not so easy to do and maintain btw).

I suggest you to have a look to [Callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) constraint which allow flexibility to validate your entity.

But if your validation logic is growing I suggest you to do a [custom validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html). It's a service so you can inject services and test it easily.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is good and will be useful to use Group sequence. In this case first will be check is price is less than and only if the first is true will be checked another two assertion
Something like that:

```
   /** 
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"Item", "Strict"}) 
 */
class Item
{

   /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")         
     * @Assert\LessThan(self::ITEM_MAX_PRICE) 
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(value=5, groups={"Strict"})
     */ 
     private float $price; 

   /** 
     * @Assert\GreaterThan(value=10, groups={"Strict"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
     */ 
     private int $stock;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it checks condition one by one, not together :(

Comment: In this way may be it is good to make custom validator with class target :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you need to look at this: https://medium.com/@gregurco.vlad/symfony-validation-trick-dependent-validation-eb48bc5e3d81